# python: How to call a function of parent class from child class object against MRO

Tags: python, inheritance, polymorphism, method-resolution-order

```
class a:
    def fun1(self):
        print 'inside a'
class b(a):
    def fun1(self):
        print 'inside b'

class c(a):
    def fun1(self):
        print 'inside c'
class d(b,c):
    pass

ob=d()
d.fun1()
```

the above code will print 'inside b' as per MRO.Is there any way to call function from class C with object of d.?

Comment: Do you mean `super()`?

Comment: Yes.. Np.. but i should be able to call fun1 with the object of d..

Comment: If you use `super` consistently, then *all* superclass implementations will get called, `a`, `b` and `c`, according to the order in the MRO. It's not clear what behaviour you're actually hoping for. If you *only* want to call `c.fun1`, ignoring the MRO, then you can do so, but this seems like a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following worked for me.

```
 ob=d()
 c.fun1(ob)  # class_name.function_name(obj reference)
```

output:
    inside c

Comment: @user1226665 this is a hacky way to do things. If you explain *what you're actually trying to achieve* you might get a better one, but the fact that you think you need to do this suggests that you have a larger design problem.

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed out, this is a bad idea, and a bad practice.

That said, the way to achieve that is:

```
class d(b,c):
    def fun1(self):
        # d uses c's fun1() instead of b's
        return c.fun1(self)
```